# [\directlua]:1: ')' expected near <eof>

Tags: luatex, tkz-euclide, lua, directlua

In most cases I get this error: [\directlua]:1: ')' expected near .

I want to calculate
`\Abs{((\bx-\ax)*(\cx-\ax)+(\by-\ay)*(\cy-\ay))/(809.55841)}` and then round up

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\makeatletter
\def\Abs#1{\directlua{tex.sprint(math.abs(#1))}}
\def\pDec#1{\directlua{tex.print(string.format('\@percentchar.12f',#1))}}
\def\Round#1#2{\directlua{tex.sprint(tostring(round(#1,#2)))}}

\def\DotProd(#1,#2,#3){%
\begingroup
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}% 
\def\ax{\strip@pt\pgf@x}%
\def\ay{\strip@pt\pgf@y}%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}% 
\def\bx{\strip@pt\pgf@x}%
\def\by{\strip@pt\pgf@y}%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}% 
\def\cx{\strip@pt\pgf@x}%
\def\cy{\strip@pt\pgf@y}%
% the following line gives the error: 
% [\directlua]:1: ')' expected near <eof>.
% \Abs #1->\directlua {tex.sprint(math.abs(#1))}
% \edef\tmp{\Abs{((\bx-\ax)*(\cx-\ax)+(\by-\ay)*(\cy-\ay))/(809.55841)}}

% the following line gives a result
\edef\tmpa{\directlua{tex.sprint(tostring(((\bx-\ax)*(\cx-\ax))/809.55841))}}

% the next line gives the same error
%\edef\tmpb{\directlua{tex.sprint(tostring(((\by-\ay)*(\cy-\ay))/809.55841))}}
 
% \edef\dotprod{\Round{\tmp}{5}}%
% \global\let\MathResult\dotprod
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{1/-2/A,5/0/B}
  \tkzDefCircle[diameter](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{O}
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,O)
  \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,O)
  \DotProd(O,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: \ay is negative and so you get two minus in a row, use `-(\ay)`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks  it's amazing! I'll have to study more lua.  Where can I find this kind of references ?

Comment: The Lua manual is in https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html but...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so I have to be careful with all subtractions if I don't know the sign of the numbers

Comment: I think your main problem is that you view `\ay` as a variable and handle it this way. But it is not a variable,  it is a macro that expands to a string, and 2--3 doesn't make sense. It would be safer if you would do in lua `local by=\by local ay=ay` and then use `by-ay` in the math.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks now I understand. I have indeed mixed lua and TeX. Are there other little traps like this one? Perhaps you can give an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

... in this case, the issue is with the indirection layer obfuscating the real issue.

I suggest doing the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}



% ======== add this part
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\directluadebug#1{
  \expandafter\directluadebugii\expandafter{\detokenize\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}}
}
\def\directluadebugii#1{
  \directlua{print() print() print("Going~to~execute:") print(token.scan_string()) print()}{#1}
  \directlua{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% ======== end add this part


\makeatletter
\def\Abs#1{\directluadebug{tex.sprint(math.abs(#1))}}
\def\pDec#1{\directluadebug{tex.print(string.format('\@percentchar.12f',#1))}}
\def\Round#1#2{\directluadebug{tex.sprint(tostring(math.round(#1,#2)))}}

\def\DotProd(#1,#2,#3){%
\begingroup
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}% 
\def\ax{\strip@pt\pgf@x}%
\def\ay{\strip@pt\pgf@y}%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}% 
\def\bx{\strip@pt\pgf@x}%
\def\by{\strip@pt\pgf@y}%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}% 
\def\cx{\strip@pt\pgf@x}%
\def\cy{\strip@pt\pgf@y}%

\edef\tmp{\Abs{((\bx-\ax)*(\cx-\ax)+(\by-\ay)*(\cy-\ay))/(809.55841)}}

\edef\tmpa{\directluadebug{tex.sprint(tostring(((\bx-\ax)*(\cx-\ax))/809.55841))}}

\edef\tmpb{\directluadebug{tex.sprint(tostring(((\by-\ay)*(\cy-\ay))/809.55841))}}
 
\edef\dotprod{\Round{\tmp}{5}}%
\global\let\MathResult\dotprod
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{-1/-2/A,-5/-7/B}
  \tkzDefCircle[diameter](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{O}
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,O)
  \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,O)
  \DotProd(O,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

If you add the part marked between "add this part" and "end add this part", then replace every `\directlua` with `\directluadebug`, then you'll be able to view the code being executed.

(there are a few small differences, in that `\directlua` expands to the "result" in a single step while `\directluadebug` requires multiple expansion steps -- this issue is fixable with `\luadef`, but in this case for simplicity I omit it)

Anyway, the content printed on the terminal is...

```lua
Going to execute:
tex.sprint(math.abs(((-142.26372--142.26372)*(-142.26372--142.26372)+(-199.1692--199.1692)*(-199.1692--199.1692))/(809.55841)))
```

A simple Lua syntax highlighter can trivially point out where the bug is.

Comment: (I have to modify the point coordinates a bit because I can't reproduce the issue locally with the original coordinates)

Comment: @AlainMatthes What do you mean?

Comment: I have not 'Going to execute:`. I have a problem I do not get the result in the terminal, I have : [\directlua]:1: ')' expected near <eof>. \directluadebugii ...))print()}{#1}\directlua {#1}

Comment: Yes the error remaining is to be expected (the modification only adds the debug logging feature, it does not fix the bug -- one way to fix the bug is to wrap the expression in parentheses as suggested in the comment) -- you should get the debug logging, I've no idea why it wouldn't -- first make sure you're using the latest LuaLaTeX version, then try something simple such as `\directlua{print("abc")}` to see if it gets printed out?

Comment: I have the latest version : This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)  (format=lualatex 2022.12.24)